# How can I take STDIN and use it on the bash shell to set an environment variable?

Tags: bash, path, sed, xargs, env

I'm trying to get better at one-liners here, this is what I have currently.

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/ubuntu/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

What I want to do is strip off that first chunk, so here's what I've figured out so far ---

```
$ echo $PATH | sed -e "s|^/[A-Za-z/]*:||"
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

The last thing I want to do here is to put that back into PATH, like export PATH=[that result]

The way I've tried this was as follows, which I can't get to work ---

```
$ echo $PATH | sed -e "s|^/[A-Za-z/]*:||" | xargs export PATH=
xargs: export: No such file or directory
```

Also, BTW, separate issue that confused me was with the sed expression above, for some reason when I tried using + rather than *, it wouldn't catch the first bit.  Look ---

```
$ echo $PATH | sed -e "s|^/[A-Za-z/]+:||" 
/home/ubuntu/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Its like the +, meaning "one or more" doesn't work as well as the "many" *.

Answer (score 12):

I think the best solution for that particular problem is:

```
export PATH=${PATH#*:}
```

But that doesn't answer the question of how to use `stdin` to set an environment variable.

It's easy to use some process' `stdout`:

```
export PATH=$(make_new_path)
```

But that's not strictly speaking using `stdin`. The obvious solution:

```
make_new_path | export PATH=$(cat)
```

won't work because the commands to the right of the pipe are executed in a subshell, so variable settings won't stick. (If it had worked, it would have been an UUOC.)

As Gordon Davisson points out in a comment, you could simply use:

```
read -r PATH; export PATH
```

Also, it is actually not necessary to `export PATH`, since `PATH` comes pre-exported, but I left it in for the case where you want to use some other environment variable.

Comment: If he actually wanted to use STDIN of the script, rather than STDOUT of some command, the proper thing to use would be `read PATH` -- but that's not what's needed here at all.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: good point. I'll fix that. It's not what is needed here, but it is the title of the question.

Comment: If you wanted to be ridiculous (and incompatible with anything but bash), you could use process redirection: `read PATH < <(make_new_path)`

Comment: +1 I think he really meant STDOUT and wrote STDIN by mistake. You did right to answer the *intent*, not the question literally. It's also nice you added the `read -r` option.

Comment: Could also add "-s" to the read to suppress echoing.

Answer (score 2):

```
export PATH=$(echo "$PATH" | sed -e "s|^/[A-Za-z/]*:||")
```

`export` is a shell built-in; that's why you can't execute it directly via `xargs` (there isn't an executable for `export`).  This runs your edit script and sets the value as the new value of `$PATH`.  As written with double quotes around `$PATH`, it works even there are multiple adjacent spaces in an element of your PATH (fairly unlikely, but no harm in making sure it works properly).

Comment: `echo $var` and `echo "$var"` are the same. You don't need those quotes. Also, `z=$(echo a b)` is the same as `z="$(echo a b)"` and `z="$(echo "a b")"`.

Comment: @janos, `echo "$var"` is very different from `echo $var` -- try it yourself with `var='*'`, or more subtly with `var="two  spaces"` (with 2 spaces between the words). bash allows you to omit the double quotes for variable assignment.

Comment: @glennjackman Damn, you're right! I also overlooked the "multiple adjacent spaces" bit, my bad, and thanks for the note!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit more simple and accurate:

```
echo "$PATH" | sed -e s/[^:]*://
```

The regular expression there is more accurate, it will work even if the first segment has numbers or spaces in it.

Btw, you do NOT need to export, because `PATH` is already exported.

The implementation of regular expressions depends on the tool. As far as I know `+` does not work in `sed`, you can do this instead:

```
echo "$PATH" | sed -e 's/[^:]\{1,\}://'
```

It seems to me that regular expressions in `sed` work similar to `vim` and different from `perl`.